Integrating a git project into another
I am working on a large repository nammed A.
However, for a specific folder of A (named cert), I want to adopt a special workflow because the code contained inside of this folder is aimed to be certified and to meet some precise certifications standards.
The goal is to extract the folder into another repository so that the developers can work separately on this part.
However, I have a LOT of scripts that uses repository A with the current architecture, moving the cert folder elswhere will break everything...
So what I want is to have the cert folder contained inside of A as it was but maintained from it's owner repository.
Obviously I already looked at git submodules, however, the issue is that a submodule is pointing to a special commit. What I want is to have the cert folder inside of A always up to date with the cert repository.
When I do git clone <url/to/A>, it would take the last version of cert on it's main branch.
If any of you have an idea it would be great
I tried git submodules and git subtree but in both cases, the "keep up to date" concept is not met

There's nothing built into git to do this.  You might be able to set up hooks, but I'd be concerned about what's effectively a blind commit if there was a breaking change to cert.

There're 2 similar solutions for you problem — submodules and [tag:git-subtree]. Neither one automatically gives you the property you want to always be on the branch tip. Sometime you you need to update the submodule/subtree in the repository A, commit the change and push. No way around that.

My advice is to use submodule, configure it with a branch and regularly run git submodule update --remote to update to the branch tip, then commit the change.
